# TypeError: undefined is not a function near this.state.cafes.map

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to pass on a cafe from my backend, but without any luck. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here, but any help would be appreciated. BTW. it's written in typescript.

```
interface Props {}
interface State {
  cafes: {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Address: string;
    PhoneNo: string;
    PriceRange: number;
    OpenTime: Date;
    CloseTime: Date;
    Zip: string;
    CustomerType: number;
    Description: string;
    City: string;
    }[];
}

export default class ListCafes extends React.Component<Props, State> {
   static navigationOptions: NavigationScreenOptions = {
    headerTitle: "Cafes"
  };

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cafes: []
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      let cafes = await json(
        "https://toobuzyservice.azurewebsites.net/cafe/zip/9000?format=json"
      );
      this.setState({ cafes });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      Alert.alert(
        "Ups! Something went wrong.. Our monkey are going to fix it! Hold on!!"
      );
    }
  }

  renderCafes() {
    return this.state.cafes.map(cafes => {
      return <CafePreviewCard key={cafes.Id} cafe={cafes} />;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>{this.renderCafes()}</ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Keep getting error: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near 'this.state.cafes.map') at renderCafes function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.state.cafes` contains non array value. check its value using `console.log(this.state.cafes)` to check that the response is not an array.

you cant map a value that is not an array.